# Charge per unit length and charge per unit area

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

In the Halliday and Resnick book, I am asked the find the linear charge density of the inner wall of a shell. This confuses me because the inner wall of a shell is an area, not a one dimensional line.

Does it make sense to find the linear charge density of an area?

Comment: If it is a cylindrical shell, then we can define it as the charge divided by the length of the cylinder

Comment: But why would you use that for charge distributed over an area? Why wouldn't you use the charger per area, aka sigma.

Comment: Maybe they are trying to make a point - like how this linear charge density is similar to the linear charge density of a line/rod.

Comment: @Goobs make it an answer. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't think that it is good enough to be an answer.